# I want to use Signup Function in Node For both Webservice and Website

Tags: node.js, web-services, express

Problem Is that i cant figure how to differentiate.

I tried `Router.post('/signup')`,

In website i want to redirect to userPage on success and

In webservice i want to send json array of response,

I am not asking to write whole code, just point me in right direction for R&D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two API end-points for signup.
Like `Router.post('/api/signup')` and `Router.post('/signup')`.

**Webservices:**

So When you call this API end point, let me say, it will return a `user` object.

```
Router.post('/api/signup', (req, res) => {
    // some stuff;
    return user;
});
```

**Website:**

In this router make a post request to `/api/signup` using some external modules like `request` or `axios` and will fetch you the user object with cookie if implemented(passport).

```
Router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    //some stuff
    request.post('http://www.example.com/signup', form: {key:'value'}}, (err, response, body) => {
        if (response.user)
            res.redirect('/point');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have different routes for website and web service. Both routes should use two middlewares.

The first middleware should do the actual signup work. You should use this middleware in both website and web service.

The second middleware should handle the aftermath. For website, this is where you do the redirection. For web service, this is where you send your JSON response.

Here is a sample code:

```
websiterouter.post('/signup', bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}), signupMiddleware, redirectionMiddleware);
webservicerouter.post('/signup', bodyParser.json(), signupMiddleware, responseMiddleware);
```

Where:

```
var signupMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    db.save({ 'username': req.body.username, 'password': req.body.password });
    next();
};

var redirectMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/userPage');
};

var responseMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    res.status(200).json({ 'successfullyRegistered': true });
};
```

**DISCLAIMER:**

1. db.save is merely a loose representation of what needs to be done.
2. Saving the user data without checking for duplicate username is probably a bad practice
3. Saving unencrypted password into the database is definitely a horrible practice and please don't do it.